# WPF C# WebClient gives exception for request on specific port and https

Tags: .net, https, webclient

This one really bugs me, I've been researching this for days without a solution. When using a WebClient POST request to a https web-url, the request takes about 30 seconds and finally crashes with a WebException saying "the underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occurred on a send". When I'm using the servers IP address instead of the name, it works and I don't get an exception. I'm getting the same behavior when using WebRequest or HttpWebRequest instead. Any browser (even when using it embedded in the Application as a WebBrowserControl) works fine with the URL.

I'm sending POST parameters with it, but that in fact doesn't matter, it's throwing the exception with or without the post data. I'm running .NET4 on Windows 7

```
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
var parameters = new NameValueCollection 
{
    {"user", "me"},
};

byte[] bytes = webclient.UploadValues("https://server.com:12345/", "POST", parameters);
```

Any help? There's a couple other posts on Stackoverflow, but none of them brought be to a solution. And yes, the SSL certificate is valid and not self signed or anything (again: browser does not have any problem with the URL).

EDIT: corrected exception with correct english message

EDIT2: maybe I should add that the server is an Apache2 on Ubuntu server behind a firewall

Comment: The phrase "Unexpected Exception during a send" doesn't seem like a valid error message that the Web Client throws. Can you please quote the exact error message?

Comment: I was trying to translate from german. I will try find the correct message. In german it's saying "unerwarteter fehler beim senden"

Answer (score 0):

Is this endpoint setup to authenticate, perhaps with Windows/NTLM?
In that case you will need to tell the Web Client object to use the [default network credential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials.aspx)s.

Is there a proxy involved?
If so, try to set the [default proxy on the Web Client object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.proxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

And please post the correct Exception error message.

Comment: No proxy involved, added correct Exception message, and setting default network credentials unfortunately did not help, as endpoint is also not setup to authenticate.